# What is the best way to measure inserts per second in MongoDB?

Tags: c#, performance, mongodb, insert

I have a multithreaded (using a threadpool) C# program that reads from a text file containing logs and batch inserts them into a MongoDB collection. I want a consistent and precise way to measure how long it takes to insert the whole file into the collection.

I can't really call a thread.join (because it's a threadpool), and I can't use a stopwatch because they're running on separate threads.

What's the next best thing?

The current way I'm doing it is the timer on my smartphone. I repeatedly call `db.collection.stats()` and wait till the count is the same as the number of logs in the file...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using C# 4.0+, I'd recommend you use the [CountdownEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.countdownevent.aspx) class. Using that class, you can just create an instance with the number of logs for example as the counter:

```
var countdown = new CountdownEvent(numberOfLogs);
```

Then, each time you complete a write to MongoDB, you signal from the worker thread:

```
countdown.Signal(); // decrement counter
```

And then, in your main process (or another thread):

```
countdown.Wait(); // returns when the count is zero
// All writes complete
```

Answer (score 1):

With `mongostat` (command line tool) you see exactly what goes on in the MongoDB server. It will give you inserts/queries etc per second. It won't automatically stop when it's done inserting, but it will definitely give you an insight to performance. The "inserts" will drop to 0 once you're done importing.

Comment: I don't know why this is happening, but when I start inserting, mongostat stops giving me regular reports about what's going on in the database. Do you know why this is the case? For instance, throughout the entire insertion process it gave me only 3 reports. With inserts being 35000, 23000, and 75000...

Comment: Are you building an index at the same time? I found it really slows down when building an index.

Comment: Watching `mongostat` though still requires the phone's timer. :)

Comment: Not sure, but mongostat doesn't lie :-) It could be disk contention or maybe the driver buffers something... unless of course those three reports happen each a second apart. In that case, you've pretty good write performance! But it should continue showing "0" for further insert values.

Comment: I was happily watching mongostat with output every second, told it to ensureIndex, and the mongostat promptly stopped showing any output until the index was built roughly 4 hours later. I'm sure it was high disk contention, but it feels like mongostat should still get its stats.